# What is difference between carto.js and cartoDB?

Tags: carto, carto-js, cartocss

I am exploring how to use carto.js map in a web application. I had seen couple of samples where carto.JS is used and some of them used cartoDB by including a supporting js file in the document.

What is the difference between carto.js and cartoDB?

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB is the former name of CARTO.

The javascript library file for CARTO.js ẁas called `cartodb.js` in versions < 4. Nowadays it is called `carto.js`.

Your other samples were from before the name change.